# How to find output nodes using tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow

I managed to train the model and got the checkpoints.
https://github.com/BichenWuUCB/squeezeDet

While trying to freeze graph, I need to know the output nodes.

What I don't understand is, what exactly are nodes?

Questions:
1. How can I figure out what is the node from tensorboard?
2. A more fundamental question, I am trying to deploy for inference, is freezegraph the right way?

Thanks.
MK

Answer (score 0):

Node is tensor. So, output nodes are output tensors, thus tensors with values that you want to obtain.

In tensorflow, you build the computational graph, that's why it's called node.

And yes, freezing the inference part of graph is good way to go for deploying for inference.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know what nodes are, I keep thinking it could be a layer.